# Getting an object property multiple times in a row vs getting it once and storing in a variable. Will the compiler optimize it anyway?

Tags: c#, performance, compiler-construction, properties, get

Is it better to store an object property when you access it multiple times in a row? Below is a rather silly example of getting an object property multiple times in a row and two ways of dealing with it. Is the example one is a good practice, if you access an object property more than once in a row? Or will the compiler be able to optimize those kinds of things anyway and it will lead to pretty much the same result?

```
  private string example1()
  {
    string prop = SomeObject.prop;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < 9000; i++;){
       builder.Append(prop);
    }
    return builder.ToString(); 
  }
private string example2(){
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i = 0; i < 9000; i++;){
    builder.Append(SomeObject.prop);
  }
  return builder.ToString();
}
```

}

If the first example is better, then is it better when you are concerned that an object does something before returning a property

```
 class SomeObject{
        public string prop
        {
            get {
                //Do something wierd
                return _prop;
            }
            set {
                _prop = value;
            }
        }
}
```

or is it better to use it even when you know that a property will be returned right away?
I'm curious about whether or not the compiler is smart enough to optimize those kinds of things automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler won't "optimize" it because it does not control if the value of the property is changing between invocations. In that case the local variable would not change but the property may change.

Answer (score 0):

Storing it in a variable is most often going to store a refrence to it, so theres really no point. You're still pointing to the same thing.

Comment: Not if the property getter returns different values for subsequent calls!